# Highcharts tree map showing wrong min value

Tags: highcharts

My highcharts tree map is showing 0 as the minimum value instead of 1. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr4mu0k1/).

```js
$('#container').highcharts({
    colorAxis: {
    minColor: '#0000FF',
    maxColor: "#ff0000",
    min: 1,
    max: 10/*,
    tickInterval: 1*/
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    data: [{
      name: '1',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 1
    }, {
      name: '2',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 2
    }, {
      name: '3',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 3
    }, {
      name: '4',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 4
    }, {
      name: '5',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 5
    }, {
      name: '6',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 6
    }, {
      name: '7',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 7
    }, {
      name: '8',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 8
    }, {
      name: '9',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 9
    }, {
      name: '10',
      value: 1,
      colorValue: 10
    }]
  }]
});
```

You can see I have explicitly set the minimum value to 1, maximum to 10, and 0 does not appear in the series. It works correctly if you uncomment the `tickInterval`, but I do not want ticks for every value in my legend.

How could I modify that so that 1 is #0000ff, 10 is #ff0000, and I have a tick at 1, 5, and 10 in my legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `min` and `max` for `colorAxis` these values may be rounded due to `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` defaulting to true.

Setting the specific tick positions will solve this problem, using `tickPositions` array  or `tickPositioner` function. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr4mu0k1/1/)):

```
colorAxis: {
    tickPositions: [1,5,10],
    min: 1,
    max: 10
    // ...
}
```